# Como leer archivo txt y meter valor a los input python

Tags: python

Hola mi problema es que no se como hacer para que al leer el archivo los valores entren en los input como opción ,el archivo.txt lo puse dentro de la misma carpeta del programa por ahora ya puedo leer archivos pero no puedo hacer que su contenido sean valores de entrada.

```
def leer():

archivo =open("leer.txt","r")
comando=archivo.readline()
while comando !="":
    print comando
    comando=archivo.readline()
archivo.close()


iniciar=0
while True:
     leer()
     comando = raw_input("Escriba help o introduzca una acción: ")
     comando = comando.lower()
     if(comando=="help"):
        print "Hola mundo"

    elif(comando=="Genero"):
        print "Dewey hola"

    elif(comando=="comandos"):
        print "comandos hola"
    else:
        print "Comando no valido"
```

Comment: el readline del archivo solo existe dentro de la funcion leer(). Haz la variable comando visible en todo el programa sacandolo fuera del bucle principal y sobre todo al principio del programa o archivo. Edito: tampoco seria valido, puesto que abres el archivo cada vez que haces leer. Abrelo antes del bucle peincipal

Comment: No entendí muy bien , no me quedo :c

Comment: Pablo la pregunta no es nada clara, en concreto ¿Qué quieres decir con  "meter valor a los input python"? ¿Qué inputs? Te refieres a que cada línea del fichero sea una condición en el propio if-elif-else?

Comment: @FJSevilla normalmente en consola yo metería el valor "comando" como dato de entra y como resultado de salida imprimiría "comandos hola". Pero ahora quiero meter en un archivo txt (leer.txt) ese valor de entrada que yo meto por consola en este caso seria la palabra comando pero utilizando un archivo.txt no se si me explique bien :c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad primero tenes que hacer que la variable `comando` se vea en todo el programa, por que ahi tenes 2 variables `comando` uno en leer que carga el dato en el archivo y otra en el cuerpo principal, una vez que la hagas "publica" tenes que sacar la asignacion que haces con `raw_input` en la variable comando, por que estas reescribiendo en valor. Un saludo.

Comment: No es tan simple, así como está el código, cuando se haya leído todo el archivo, el programa quedará en un loop infinito por el `while True:`

Comment: Claro, el condicional del while lo tiene que arreglar, ademas si quiere hacer varios comando que estan en el archivo, la logica tambien esta mal, por que leer() siempre devuelve el primer valor o lectura del archivo, pero en primera instancia era solucionar por que no puede tomar el valor guardado en el archivo, despues el codigo falla por otras cosas.